# Setting up build and deployment for a solution which have three web projects that needs to be deployed with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a solution in **VS** where I have multiple projects but three of them need to be *deployed in different azure web applications.*

I have read tutorials where all of them show you these *simple steps*:

> 1. Setting up a build (pointing a .sln file)
> 2. Getting an artifact in a .zip file
> 3. Setting up a release pipeline where you select the artifacts (.zip file) and select the azure web application you want to deploy the artifact.

All that is fairly simple and works well when you have one web application in your solution. In my case it doesn't work because I think the artifacts have multiple application and I'm not giving any information to the deployment pipeline how it will select only one application from the `zip` file for each **Azure Web Application**.

How is the better way to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your way of build. Instead of building the solution `(.sln)` you can use `(.csproj)` *(assuming you have a common .sln file which is having multiple .csporj)*

Steps:

1. Setting up the build - pointing `projectA.csproj`
2. Setting up the build - pointing `projectB.csproj`
3. Setting up the build - pointing `projectC.csproj`
4. Getting all the artifact in a separate zip ( 3 zip)
5. During the release you can deploy the corresponding artifact (zip) to your azure web apps

---

Lets say if you have a common `.sln` which is having a 3 separate `.sln` solutions. you can follow [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227343/triggering-azure-devops-builds-based-on-changes-to-sub-folders/53229588#53229588)