# DevOps - Disabling stages in a release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a Release pipeline with ~20 stages. Depending on the kind of release we are doing, we decide to run some subset of these stages.

Running each stage is expensive and we do not want to run it unless absolutely necessary.

Is there a direct way to disable some stages at the time of kicking off the release, so that we execute only the absolute necessary stages in the release?

If not, then what is the best programmatic way of achieving this behavior?

Comment: It sounds like you should have multiple release pipelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, there is no option to disable the stages based on the conditions. I'd suggest you can submit [feedback for this feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html)

As Daniel Suggest you should create separate release pipelines for your use case

Another option is to you can define that conditions in the task level with your stages to skip.

For Example,

You have 3 stages:

- DEV
- QA
- PROD

Each Stage have 2 task:

- Task 1
- Task 2

Let say if you don't want to deploy in QA.

Then you can define your **custom condition** for the 2 Tasks in QA in order to **skip the execution.**

You can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229588/7073340) for working with custom conditions.

Answer (score 7):

It is very simple: Just use "condition" false or true; it will skip your stage; e.g.,

```
stages:
- stage: "CreateTemplates"  
  condition: "false"
```

[image: click here for stage condition example]

Comment: Wonderful! Not documented but working like a charm! I've just used False (without double quotes) as it is recognized as Boolean from MS.

Comment: Same here, I can confirm this works :)

Comment: Don't work if `- template:` is used

Answer (score 3):

When starting the pipeline through the ADO webinterface, ADO now lets you specify which stages to run.
[image: ADO screenshot: select stages to run]

If you prefer to select the stages programmatically, then you can use conditions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A

# stage B runs if A fails
- stage: B
  condition: failed()

# stage C runs if B succeeds
- stage: C
  dependsOn:
  - A
  - B
  condition: succeeded('B')
```