# Conditional build solution in Azure DevOps

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am working on a large scale application which uses multiple small-small project/solutions. Each solution is built in their respective agents. Similar to below screenshot 
[image]

Now the problem is that all the projects/solutions are compiled even if a single project file is changed.

To reduce CI build time, I want to add conditional expression in the build which would build the project only if their respective source is changed.

I know this can be achieved in Azure DevOps via `Custom condition using variable expressions`. But I am not sure how can I check if the respective source code is changed
[image]

Does anyone know what `variable expression` I need to write here?

Comment: well, it depends on what your condition needs to be

Comment: My requirement is to check if folder xx has any code changes, if yes build abc solution. How can I write this expression?

Comment: You can't achieve it with the custom conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Well as I see your are using the Git Repo, you can do this in the below way

As a very first step you need to find whether which project/solution is modified.

You can find the solution from my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227343/triggering-azure-devops-builds-based-on-changes-to-sub-folders/53229588#53229588),where you can see I've used a simple powershell script to pull out the modified files, and enables the corresponding variables.

*Sample Powershell script to pull-out the modified files*

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
$temp=$files -split ' '
$count=$temp.Length
echo "Total changed $count files"
For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
{
  $name=$temp[$i]
  echo "this is $name file"
  if ($name -like "SubFolderA/*")
    {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MicroserviceAUpdated]True"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about **TFVC** repo with same scenario?

Comment: @DhartiSutariya this only applies to git, for TFVC you can check [this commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1):

you cant achieve that with condition. condition are for executing tasks inside build. you are looking for build triggers in yaml files:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - path\to\app\*
```

this build will only trigger when anything under `path\to\app\ folder was changed. that way you create a build per app and can isolate those builds to specific files changed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts&tabs=schema#pipeline

Comment: I can't create build per app. This would break CT and CD pipeline

Comment: i dont know what is ct, but that leaves you with no options, you can examine current commit and see what files were changed and make decisions based on that