# Azure DevOps Conditional Build Step

Tags: azure-devops

I have a solution with two projects.

```
Integration.Api
Integration.Common
```

In Azure DevOps, I have steps which run for the `Integration.Api` project, I also have these build steps to create a NuGet package for the `Integration.Common` project:

```
dotnet Pack Common
dotnet Nuget Push
```

What do I put in the Custom condition textbox so that the step runs only if the `Integration.Common` project has changed? ie. I still want the build to run if `Integration.Api` has changed, but I only want the dotnet Pack steps to run if `Integration.Common` has changed.
[image: Azure DevOps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I put in the Custom condition textbox so that the step runs only if the Integration.Common project has changed?

There is no such out of box expressions.

But you can **use a powershell script to pull out the modified files, and enables the corresponding variables**, then add expressions in the custom condition textbox based on the value of variables.

Ticket: [Conditional build solution in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264965/conditional-build-solution-in-azure-devops/54277305#54277305)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'd need to put condition on build, not on step. Put such a trigger condition on the build where you want to build common components.

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - /path/to/common/*
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#triggers

Comment: But I want the build to run if Integration.Api is updated.

Comment: well, then do it vice versa

Comment: I need the build to run regardless of which project changes. There are other build steps which are run before the dotnet build steps. I only want the dotnet build steps to run if Common has been updated.

Comment: Is there some way to check the last modified date of the dll? If the last modified date of Integration.Common.dll is greater than the one currently deployed then run dotnet Pack.

Comment: you need to separate this build into 2 different builds and use packages