# Release is triggered even though build does not publish artifact

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, build-pipeline

Last week, our team decided to move all separate .NET projects into a single solution. Because we were already using Azure DevOps with separate build pipelines for each project, we looked into the possibility to only trigger builds whenever there are changes to a specific project. This, to prevent the build agents from rebuilding the entire solution on every commit.

Because our source repository is a locally hosted Git one, we do not have the niceties of using path filters, so we resorted to using a Powershell task to determine if all upcoming tasks should be skipped, using a custom condition (explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227343/triggering-azure-devops-builds-based-on-changes-to-sub-folders/) SO question).

Now, on every commit, all builds are triggered, but the builds resolve for themselves if they should continue to build and (more importantly) if they should publish a build artifact at the end. An example of such a skipped build is below:

[image: Skipped Azure DevOps build example]

However, every time such a build 'succeeds', a new artifact is created, even though the publish artifact task is skipped. The problem is that all our release pipelines are triggered when a build pipeline creates an artifact. So every time a build is skipped like shown above, the release pipeline triggers and tries to deploy the artifact. But it fails, because the artifact it uses to deploy does not really exist (it seems like it is empty, and the build pipeline actually doesn't mention an artifact on the Summary tab), so any operations on the artifact fail in the release pipeline.

Our release pipelines are set to trigger on **source type** `build artifact`, for the corresponding build pipeline, with the **default version** parameter set to `latest`.

How is it possible that, even though the publish artifact task is skipped, the release pipeline still triggers and tries to deploy an empty artifact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming you enable the Continues Delivery in the Releases pipelines, this option is **not** related to build artifacts. this option means that Release will be triggered when the build succeeded (not matter if he has artifacts or no).

So this is the reason why after each build a new release started.

As workaround, you can add a task in the build that add "build tag" only when there is a artifacts, and in the release artifacts options, instead of choose `Latest` you can choose `Latest from the build pipeline default branch with tags` and specify the tag you put in the build.
Another option is in the "Stages" click on the triggers and then it's configured to "After release" so enable the "Artifact filters" and specify there the build tag.

How do you add a build tag? add a PowerShell task with this command:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]test-tag"
```

Comment: The solution you provided works indeed, however I did need to use the `artifact filters` option. Without it (so only using the `Latest from the build pipeline [...]` option) the releases were still deployed. After specifying the `artifact filters` the release properly halted with the message `Artifact conditions not met`.