# Trouble Getting Changeset Details With Powershell From Within CI Build

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am trying to implement the powershell code that is mentioned in the answer to the following question.
[Triggering Azure DevOps builds based on changes to sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227343/triggering-azure-devops-builds-based-on-changes-to-sub-folders)

My simple attempt to access DevOps results in the following error.
[image]

This is the simple powershell code I am trying first. It is the code that caused the error depicted above.

`tf changeset /collection:"https://*******.visualstudio.com/******************" 25490`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trouble Getting Changeset Details With Powershell From Within CI Build

I could reproduce this issue with error `URL` in parameter `/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl` or do not have permission to access the corresponding collection.

To resolve this issue, first, we nee make sure the URL is correct. The URL should be the **Team Project Collection**:

```
tf changeset /collection:http://***.visualstudio.com/YourCollectionName
```

Second, if you do not have permission to access that collection, please add a PAT, which have permission to access that collection to the URL:

```
tf changeset /collection:http://<YouPATHere>@***.visualstudio.com/YourCollectionName
```

As test, it works fine on my side:

```
tf changeset /collection:http://<PAT>@.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection 138
```

[image]

Hope this helps.