# Build only projects which are changed in a solution -Azure CI pipeline - YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have multiple projects under a solution,

```
ProjectA.csproj
projectB.csproj
projectC.csproj
```

I have created a YAML CI build pipeline for this solution with trigger from Master Branch

"trigger: - Master"

Whenever a check-in happens to Master for any of the project above, it triggers the CI pipeline and create artifacts for all the above individual projects.

Question - can I only build projects which have changes using the same single YAML file for the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question - can I only build projects which have changes using the same
>   single YAML file for the solution?

Yes, you can. Assuming you have multiple `jobs/steps` for different projects, you can use [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to determine when it should *run/skip* some specific steps. You can check this example:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
      $temp=$files -split ' '
      $count=$temp.Length
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
      {
        $name=$temp[$i]
        echo "this is $name file"
        if ($name -like "ProjectA/*")
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunProjectA]True"
          }
        if ($name -like "ProjectB/*")
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunProjectB]True"
          }
        if ($name -like "ProjectC/*")
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunProjectC]True"
          }
      }

- script: echo "Run this step when ProjectA folder is changed."
  displayName: 'Run A'
  condition: eq(variables['RunProjectA'], 'True')

- script: echo "Run this step when ProjectB folder is changed."
  displayName: 'Run B'
  condition: eq(variables['RunProjectB'], 'True')

- script: echo "Run this step when ProjectC folder is changed."
  displayName: 'Run C'
  condition: eq(variables['RunProjectC'], 'True')
```

Then if we only have changes in `ProjectA` folder, only those steps/tasks with `condition: eq(variables['RunProjectA'], 'True')` will run. You should have three separate build tasks in your pipeline for `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and `ProjectC`, and give them your custom condition, then you can only build projects which have changes... (Hint from **Jayendran** in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229588/10910450)!)

Hope it works.

Comment: Is this really the best answer? It seems inelegant. Is there a way to trigger on a particular directory change in a git repo?

Answer (score 1):

Add the allowPackageConflicts input. It allows publish of just a single project in the solution. Only projects with an updated version number is published.

```
# publish to artifacts:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? How does the version number get changed?

Comment: Update the version numbers under Project Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information before making the commit.