# Azure pipeline filter github user on commit

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to filter a github user to not trigger a pipeline if a commit is pushed?

E.g. if a bot-user pushes some changes, the git-pipeline should not be triggered. I only find information to trigger changed files or branch-names.

Comment: There's no such out-of-box feature. Once we enable the CI trigger, the pipeline will be triggered no matter who commit the change... For now the filter of CI trigger only supports [branches, paths and tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) but not committers. An alternative workaround should be adding one CMD/PS task to get the user ID, then we can fail the pipeline run at the first task or skip the following tasks to save the time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to filter a github user to not trigger a pipeline if a
> commit is pushed?

**No**, for now Azure Devops [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) only supports filters like `Branches`, `Paths` and `Tags`. It doesn't have filter for specific users, so the pipeline will always be triggered if there're changes committed.(No matter who pushes the commit)

**Possible workaround:**

One alternative workaround is to add PS task to filter the user and fail/complete the pipeline at that task, it would save much time. In such scenario, the pipeline will be triggered but it will finish immediately.

We can use `git log --format='%ae' $(Build.SourceVersion)^!` command to get the Id  of the user who makes the commit. `$(Build.SourceVersion)` represents commit id.

In my test, a user in github organization has the Id format like `xxxxxx+accountName@users.noreply.github.com`.(You can use the command to find the Id of the user you want to filter first)

**Simple example:**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $Id = (git log --format='%ae' $(Build.SourceVersion)^!)
      if ($Id -like "5xxxxxx6+lancexxx@users.noreply.github.com")
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
          }
      if ($Id -like "xxx")
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]"
          }

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Hello world
...
```

We can add a PS task at the first of pipeline, it would be used to filter the specific user. The task would fail if the author of the pushed commit is someone `5xxxxxx6+lancexxx@users.noreply.github.com`.

You can use conditional steps to skip the following tasks if you don't want to fail the pipeline run, so the pipeline run will report `succeed` and it won't take much time. See [conditional steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62165868/10910450).