# How to tell in an Azure DevOps pipeline what files have changed during a build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am trying to see if there is a way that I can tell while files have changed during a build, we are wanting to run this pipeline a few times a day, and I only what the files that have changed in that build, I found this article, which is somewhat close but we do not have the file structure like they do so just plugging in a few variables will not work in this case [How to get only changed files using Azure devops pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088433/how-to-get-only-changed-files-using-azure-devops-pipelines)

the problem that I am running into is the artifcat from the build over-writes what is on our share during the publish process so I have no way to compare this folder with another.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thanks all!

Comment: What is the specific scenario you're trying to implement here? Please provide more background on **why** you want to determine this.

Comment: we are updating our code several times a day, and we only want to push what has changed to production, we do not want to push the entire app, just the few files that have been updated, but the artifact goes direct to a files share and it overwrites all of the files so I cannot tell that only say 15 files were updated.  Does that help clarify?