# Run DevOps Agent Job based on Subfolder Commit

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have enabled CI and set a pipeline trigger with on main and applied path filters for 2 folders A and B.

I want to create 2 agents jobs X and Y which runs tasks based on the trigger.
Example: If the trigger is due to changes in folder A, then Agent X should run and if the trigger is due to changes in folder B, then Agent Y should run.

What exactly is the condition that should be kept in order to implement this scenario.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229588/1185136

Answer (score 0):

in your situation, you can create two yaml files in the repo and create two pipeline based on them.

Jusk like below.

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - A/

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

And

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - B/

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to implement this scenario in a single pipeline